# How to find the all positions of first element and get the elements at once from the nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two questions.
Let's think the following expression.

```
expr = {plus, {minus, 2, 3}, {times, 1, 2}}
```

**Q1**
I want to get something like `at once`
**INPUT:**

```
AllHeadPositions[expr]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
expr->{{1}}
minus->{{2,1}}
times->{{3,1}}
```

and 
**Q2**(MAIN)
want to get elements at one list something like

**INPUT**

```
expr[[{something to specifiy minus}]]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{minus,2,3}
```

For 1st question,I have found the way

```
If[Not[NumberQ[#]], {#, Position[expr, #]}, Nothing] & /@ 
 Flatten[expr]
```

but what to do for the second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Thread[Extract[expr, #] -> #] & Position[expr, _Symbol, Heads -> False]
```

> {plus -> {1}, minus -> {2, 1}, times -> {3, 1}}

```
expr[[Position[expr, {minus, __}][[1, 1]]]]
```

> {minus, 2, 3}

Also

```
First@Cases[{minus, __}]@expr
```

> {minus, 2, 3}

Answer (score 4):

For the second question:

```
expr[[Sequence @@ Most @@ Position[expr, minus]]]
```

> {minus, 2, 3}

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = {plus, {minus, 2, 3}, {times, 1, 2}};
```

Question 1

```
Transpose[{
  Replace[expr, {a_, __} :> a, {1}],
  Position[expr, _Symbol, Heads -> False]}]
```

{{plus, {1}}, {minus, {2, 1}}, {times, {3, 1}}}

Question 2

```
First@ Extract[Position[expr, {minus, __}]] @ expr
```

{minus, 2, 3}

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = {plus, {minus, 2, 3}, {times, 1, 2}};
```

**Question 1**: Using `SequecenCases` and `Position`.

```
patt = s : {_Symbol} :> Splice /@ {s, Position[#, s[[1]]]} &;

SequenceCases[Flatten@#, patt@#] &@expr 

(*{{plus, {1}}, {minus, {2, 1}}, {times, {3, 1}}}*)
```

**Question 2**: Using `SequencePosition`.

```
#[[First @@ SequencePosition[Flatten@#, {minus}]]] &@expr

(*{minus, 2, 3}*)
```